# How to "sort" .torrent files by tracker?

Tags: shell, bittorrent

I have a directory with a lot of `.torrent` files, and I want to get only the one with specific tracker(s). Is there a way to find them?

The only way I've found so far is to add them all in a bittorrent client, and look one by one in the tracker list, but it's tedious. Do you know another way, via Powershell maybe or some other software? On Unix I would have tried to `grep` them, but `.torrent` are binary so I'm not even sure it would have worked.

Comment: If you don't mind, a quick-and-dirty method is to use `strings` on them and `grep` for hostnames.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but do I have access to these commands on Windows? I'm quite used to them on a Unix environment, but I've almost never used command line on Windows (since DOS with Windows 95)

Answer (score 0):

Try [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), it worse than `grep`, but it does work:

```
findstr /i /m /r /c:":announce[0-9]*:http://your\.tracker\.com" *.torrent
```

- `/i`  - Case-insensitive search
- `/m`  - Print only the filename if a file contains a match
- `/r`  - Use string as a regular expression
- `/c:"string"` - Use string as a literal search string